# Error with JSON: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 23 (char 22)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Hello I am reading and save a dict of dicts in JSON format, but when I use the json load I get this error.I still need to figure out what problem is it, what's the problem there? Thank you!!

JSON example:

```
data = {'multiplayer.it': {'news1.it': (title,date), 'news2.it': (title,date)}, 
        'site2.it':{'news2.it':(title,date), 'news3.it': (title,date)}}
```

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=30)
async def get_gamesnews():
    sites = ['https://multiplayer.it/articoli/notizie/']
    for site in sites:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
            async with ses.get(site) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    text = await response.text()
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
                    if site == 'https://multiplayer.it/articoli/notizie/':
                        div_news = soup.find_all('div', class_='media-body')
                        for news in div_news:
                            titles = news.find_all('a', class_='text-decoration-none')
                            for title in titles:
                                title_news = title.text.strip()
                                link_news = 'https://multiplayer.it' + title['href']

                                with open('dictionary_news.json', 'r+') as f:
                                    dict_news = json.load(f)
                                    dictvalues_news = dict_news.get('multiplayer.it')
                                    if link_news not in dictvalues_news:
                                        date_news = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                                        dict_news['multiplayer.it'][link_news] = (title_news, date_news)
                                        print((title_news, link_news, date_news))
                                        channel = client.get_channel(855220263917191228)
                                        await channel.send(f'{title_news} {link_news}')
                                        json.dump(dict_news, f)
```

That's how I create the json file:

```
import json
data = {'multiplayer.it': {}}

with open('dictionary_news.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```

Traceback:

```
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'get_gamesnews'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thund\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Thund\Desktop\RepoBitbucket\DiscordBot\main.py", line 75, in get_gamesnews
    dict_news = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\Thund\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\Thund\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Thund\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Thund\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON?

Comment: data = {'multiplayer.it': {'news1.it': (title,date), 'news2.it': (title,date)}, 'site2.it':{'news2.it':(title,date), 'news3.it': (title,date)}} this is an example of the dict I want to save, (values and keys changes overtime)

Comment: You should try printing the actual data inside the dictionary_news.json file, because that traceback looks like its saying that the file is empty.

Comment: if I print the file with f.read() I get {"multiplayer.it": {}}, then after next line (load) I get the error

Comment: Now it seems I get another error, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 23 (char 22)

Comment: Seems like you can't read and write in the same time, or I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're running json.dump(), after which json.load() can't be executed any more without reopening the file (at least to my knowledge, there might be workarounds).

Also remember that "r+" open the file in append mode, so that code would probably cause other problems latter.

I would recommend changing the code like this:

```
with open('dictionary_news.json', 'r') as f:
    dict_news = json.load(f)

for title in titles:
    title_news = title.text.strip()
    link_news = 'https://multiplayer.it' + title['href']
    dictvalues_news = dict_news.get('multiplayer.it')
    if link_news not in dictvalues_news:
        date_news = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        dict_news['multiplayer.it'][link_news] = (title_news, date_news)
        print((title_news, link_news, date_news))
        channel = client.get_channel(855220263917191228)
        await channel.send(f'{title_news} {link_news}')

with open('dictionary_news.json', 'w') as f:   
    json.dump(dict_news, f)
```

Since json.dump() writes the entire json, you should use mode 'w' for writing to the file.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks, I kinda imagine it was an error like that, cause I wanted to do the read and write at the same time